# How do I post a bulleted list using the slack api

Tags: kotlin, slack-api, slack-block-kit

## Background

I am trying to use the slack bolt jdk along with the following dependencies:

```
  // Slack bolt SDK
  implementation("com.slack.api:bolt:1.8.1")
  implementation("com.slack.api:bolt-servlet:1.8.1")
  implementation("com.slack.api:bolt-jetty:1.8.1")
  implementation("com.slack.api:slack-api-model-kotlin-extension:1.8.1")
  implementation("com.slack.api:slack-api-client-kotlin-extension:1.8.1")
```

### What I want to achieve (in slack)

[image]

### What I currently am getting (in slack)

[image]

### What I've tried so far

```
fun SlashCommandContext.sendSectionAndAck(
  message: String,
): Response {
  slack.methods(botToken).chatPostMessage { req ->
    req
      .channel(channelId)
      .blocks {
        section {
          markdownText(message)
        }
      }
  }
  return ack()
}
```

It seems like the markdown is being formatted *almost* properly. The header and footer are both bold as intended, but for some reason, the bulleted list is not being formatted correctly. I have also tried replacing the `*` with `-` without any luck.

In my case, I can call the function with the following input:

```
val input = """
*Some header text in bold*
- item
- another item
*Some footer text also in bold*
"""
sendSectionAndAck(input)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 23):

The easiest workaround for this would be **using **'•'** character** itself in the text.

Slack also uses following as part of the block kit message to reflect bullet points:

```
"text": "• test",

"blocks": [
    {
      "type": "rich_text",
      "block_id": "erY",
      "elements": [
        {
          "type": "rich_text_list",
          "elements": [
            {
              "type": "rich_text_section",
              "elements": [
                {
                  "type": "text",
                  "text": "test"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "style": "bullet",
          "indent": 0
        }
      ]
    }
```

Another reference:

 https://superuser.com/questions/1282510/how-do-i-make-a-bullet-point-in-a-slack-message

Comment: Fair enough I guess.

Comment: Any pointer to documentation on the rich_text block type?  It's not in the Slack reference https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/blocks

Comment: Ah, found this: https://api.slack.com/changelog/2019-09-what-they-see-is-what-you-get-and-more-and-less

Answer (score 1):

A simple jq script to prefix a stream of lines read from stdin with bullets for the purposes of pasting into a slack message:

`jq -rR '"\u2022 \(.)"'`

Answer (score 0):

Use the rich text blocks. The best and easiest way would be to use the [Block Kit Builder](https://app.slack.com/block-kit-builder/) by Slack. You can edit in WYSIWYG and get the payload generated for you.

```json
{
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "rich_text",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "rich_text_section",
                    "elements": [
                        {
                            "type": "text",
                            "text": "Hello, this is some regular text.\n\n"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "rich_text_list",
                    "style": "bullet",
                    "indent": 0,
                    "border": 0,
                    "elements": [
                        {
                            "type": "rich_text_section",
                            "elements": [
                                {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "text": "SPOC 1 <"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "link",
                                    "url": "mailto:email@example.com",
                                    "text": "email@example.com"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "text": ">"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "rich_text_section",
                            "elements": [
                                {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "text": "SPOC 2 <"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "link",
                                    "url": "mailto:email2@example.com",
                                    "text": "email2@example.com"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "text": ">"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "rich_text_section",
                    "elements": [
                        {
                            "type": "text",
                            "text": "\nAnd here is some more text, some "
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "text",
                            "text": "bold",
                            "style": {
                                "bold": true
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "text",
                            "text": " text, some "
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "text",
                            "text": "italic",
                            "style": {
                                "italic": true
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "text",
                            "text": " text too!"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Generates the following output:

[image: Output]

Hope this helps.