# Slack API won't generate bulleted list layout

Tags: java, kotlin, slack-api, slack-block-kit

I'm trying to send a bulleted list as a Slack message.

However this structure is pretty verbose (as explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68483110/3103891)) and for some reason I get an `invalid_blocks` error as a response.

```
RichTextBlock.builder()
    .elements(
        listOf(
            RichTextListElement.builder()
                .elements(
                    listOf(
                        RichTextSectionElement.builder()
                           .elements(listOf(SlackTextElement("test")))
                           .build()
                    )
                )
                .style("bullet")
                .indent(0)
                .build()
        )
    )
.build()
```

Where `SlackTextElement` is a (Java) class which I implemented, in order to match the example from the answer I mentioned above.

```
public class SlackTextElement implements RichTextElement {
    String text;
    String type = "text";

    public SlackTextElement(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this? Alternatively, to debug Slack's API?