# Slack blocks nested bullet point list

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit

I need to send a API request to slack with a message containing a nested bullet point list. I've found the following answer to a existing question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68483110/16659015 but sadly this only shows a normal bullet point list without nesting.

I couldn't find any resources or documentation to this `rich_text` and `rich_text_list` types and when trying different orders the block kit builder threw errors.

How can I utilize the blocks with rich_text to create a nested bullet point list?

(I know there are workarounds but if a 1 dimensional bulletpoint exists through blocks then a nested should also be possible somehow)

Comment: The only documentation I could find on rich_text is this changelog from 2019: https://api.slack.com/changelog/2019-09-what-they-see-is-what-you-get-and-more-and-less